# CSS Flex - LI align every second flex item on first item max width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular5

On my application I have a something like that :

```
 <ul>
   <li> ... </li>
   <li> ... </li>
   <li> ... </li> 
 </ul>
```

Each `<li>` has `display: flex;` , and I would like to align every second flex item on the max-width between all first items.

To make it more clear, bellow you will find a pic to show what I am trying to achieve :

[image]

What are the existing CSS properties that I could play with to achieve that ?

**EDIT**: As requested bellow you'll find the code from my current angular application :

```css
.item1 {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.item2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <a class="item1">tata is magic</a>
      <a class="item2">Control OK</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="item1">titi is very very slow</a>
      <a class="item2">Control KO</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="item1">toto</a>
      <a class="item2">Control OK</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**Html with angular**

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let key of keys">
  <a class="item1">{{key}}</a>
  <span *ngIf="controlExists"><a class="item2">Control OK</a></span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: show your full code(relevant code to question)

Comment: ok i'll edit the question.

Comment: Not sure it's possible with flex and li tags. Maybe tables.

Comment: For this all the first items have to be in a div, and all the second items also need to have their own div,  This will make it so your first div gets the width of the longest element and the second div will just be inline-block next to it

Comment: @Viira I did remove the angular part with full html

Comment: That's not possible as neither of the `a` can see eah other and therefore won't align as you ask. Using CSS Table will though (unless a markup change is possible), where the `ul` is displayed as `table`, the `li` as `table-row` and `a` as `table-cell`

Comment: @LGSon what do you think of Łukasz Blaszyński answer, trying it out it is working well ?

Comment: @LoganWlv As I said, if a markup change is possible then I would recommend to use Flexbox instead of CSS Table. The next question is how that markup should look like, which will come down to how the responsiveness should behave. E.g. with that answer you might get issues on small devices, as it won't easily be possible to pair them vertical. If you need that, accept an answer here and then post another with those requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/w6mzugc0/14/

See my fiddle. The solution is to have 2 lists i think. You shoudl use flex on lists-wrapeer and the flex on each li.

```
<div class='lists-wrapper'>
  <ul>
     <li> <div class='item1'>11111111111</div> </li>
     <li> <div class='item1'>333333333</div></li>
    <li> <div class='item1'>55</div> </li>
    <li> <div class='item1'>77</div></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
     <li> <div class='item2'>22222</div> </li>
     <li> <div class='item2'>44</div></li>
    <li> <div class='item2'>666</div> </li>
    <li> <div class='item2'>888888</div></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and styling:

```
li {
  display: flex;
}

.item1 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}

.item2 {
  padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.lists-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best way but its hard to fix this with his angular setup

Comment: It depends, Maybe single ngFor can be replaced with 2 ones and each one displays needed part of data. In main post i can see simple html.

Comment: Yeah I removed the angular part because I thought it would have no impact on the solution. Normally using yours with double *ngFor it still should work and print it with the same order

Comment: Following @Jeremy edit, I did put back the angular part. I'm trying your answer right now with double *ngFor

Comment: @ŁukaszBlaszyński it is working well, with the correct order . Though I am not 100% sure if your solution is subject to unwanted behaviors with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Not with flexbox but CSS Tables can do that although an extra span is required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  display: table;
}

a {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: .5em;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

.item1 span {
  background: lightblue;
}

.item2 span {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="item1"><span>Lorem ipsum</span></a>
    <a class="item2"><span>Control OK</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="item1"><span>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</span></a>
    <a class="item2"><span>Control OK</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="item1"><span>toto</span></a>
    <a class="item2"><span>Control OK</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `table` itself or some `div`s with `display: table`.

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

span  {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>First item</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Just item</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Item</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Some item</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Realy very long item</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Kek</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```